# Incrementing for loop in python when condition matched

Tags: python, for-loop

EDIT: Problem was due to a different part of my code. I thought it was the for loop

I have a for loop in python that goes like this:

```
for x in OrderedList:
    if x in ResultList1:
        print x, '1'
    elif x in ResultList2:
        print x, '2'
    elif x in ResultList3:
        print x, '3'
```

The problem is if it finds `x` in `ResultList1` and `ResultList2`, it prints `x,'1'` and `x,'2'` but I want it to get the next value for `x` if it finds x in `ResultList1`, not look in 2 and 3 also.

Comment: since you have elif it should only be entering one of you cases..you could include orderedlist so we can see it or show the actual output of the function since it almost certainly does not print "x"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code already does that.

The other way you can move to the next element is to use `continue`:

```
for x in OrderedList:
    if x in ResultList1:
        print x, '1'
        continue
    if x in ResultList2:
        print x, '2'
        continue
    if x in ResultList3:
        print x, '3'
        continue
```

However it's unnecessary here because you are using `elif`.

Comment: good that you gave him the info...however it wont do anything for whatever behavior he is seeing...since he is already using elif(as you said)...he has some other fundamental flaw or missing element

Comment: Sorry this is part of a much larger program and I was having a problem elsewhere that was causing this issue. I thought it was the for loop. Thanks for the response